# How to open telegram web application by button from channel (not private chat)?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

Is there a way to open the Web Application in Telegram from a channel by clicking on button? That is, what is the algorithm?

Adding a bot to the channel
The bot sends a message with the button
The user clicks the button and the application opens in Telegram.

Problem: The message with the right button is not sent. Error:

> [error_code] => 400
> [description] => Bad Request: BUTTON_TYPE_INVALID

My code:

```
$telegram = new Telegram($bot_api_key, $bot_username);

  $keyboard = [
      "inline_keyboard" => [
          [
               [
                 'text' => 'Open App',
                 'web_app' => ['url' => 'https://test.com/bot.php'],
               ]
          ]
      ]
  ];
  $result = Request::sendMessage([
    'chat_id' => $chat_id,
    'parse_mode' => 'markdown',
    'text'    => 'Test message',
    'reply_markup' => $keyboard
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

No way!

What you want works for BoT sent messages in private chats only, not on Channel or Groups.

Since, web or webview may have vulnerabilities/scripts, and is not hosted on telegram servers, but users, it is made such to avoid such instances.

You can however simple send a link button which opens with a prompt to open link in telegran official client(s).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33357283)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Look, this type of button is used here: https://t.me/RandomGod/5572 . There are no restrictions. I don't know how they did it, but it is possible to send such messages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create **/newapp** via botFather
2. Create an inline button with a normal link, like this **https://t.me/your_bot/your_app?startapp**

example:

```
$msg['text'] = "Message";
$msg["reply_markup"] = json_encode(["inline_keyboard" => [
    [["text"=>"button","url"=>"https://t.me/your_bot/your_app?startApp"]]]
]);
tlgrm("sendMessage", $msg, $user);
```